# google chrome: radio button not appearing in webpage

Tags: html

The radio button in the form is not visible in chrome/Sometime it do appear and again disappear.In some website i got bug in chrome with radio button.But i dint get any solution to solve this.Anyone know about this? This is a sample of form where i am getting problem with radio box.

```
<form method="get" action="http://www.google.in/search" style="width:244" target="_blank">
    <table width="242" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0"  style="font-size:10px">
        <tr>
            <td width="242"><img src=googlelogo.gif style="padding-top:6px;"/>
                <input type="text"   name="q" size="14" maxlength="255" value=""/>
                <input type="submit" value="Search" style="width:52px;">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-top:3px;">
                <input type="radio"  name="sitesearch" value="" />The Web
                <input type="radio"  name="sitesearch" value="website.com" width="auto" height="auto" checked="checked"/>website.com
                <br />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: You shouldn't really be using a table for this layout as it's not tabular data that you're displaying. Also you don't have a <form></form> tags present in the code you've pasted.

Comment: i corrected the code.both radio buttons are not visible in chrome

Comment: When I pasted the exact code from above adding in html and body tags to the beginning and end, it worked completely fine in both Firefox and Chrome. Could you give us a link to a page that has the issue? Is there more code? As suggested before, I would get rid of the table in this example simply because it's not needed. There does not seem to be anything else wrong with your code. Try refreshing the cache?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using HTML4 or 5?

In HTML 5, the width, align, cellpadding are obsolete for the table tag.

Also, delete the 0 in the border attribute, just use border="", since it only allows an empty string or 1.

the width attribute for td is also obsolete.

Also try to delete the width and height attributes on the radiobutton. If it works, fix it in the CSS instead. But firstly delete it!